# How does WP handle multiple matching rewrite rules?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, theme-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Here is my url to a custom type :

```
http://host/movie/my-slug
```

When I go to this link, I'm redirected to

```
http://host/movie/my-slug/?post_type=movie
```

which results in a 404 error.

I use [Rewrite Rule Inspector wordpress plugin](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.org%2Fextend%2Fplugins%2Frewrite-rules-inspector%2F&ei=8Y93UJeCO4aM0AXfw4HQAw&usg=AFQjCNGMzrBwDFSKDIFg4GW2mn3nG6zNrQ&sig2=sBmIwCT88AxpxB4wP9Fheg) for listing the matching rewrite rules.

It appears that my url matches three rules : (regex new-url source)

- movie/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$    index.php?post_type=movie&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2] movie
- (.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$  index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2] page
- [^/]+/([^/]+)/?$  index.php?attachment=$matches[1]    post

Witch one Wordpress will choose for resolving my url ? 
Why do I have a 404 error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it matches the first one in the array. So you enter specific rules above more general ones. In your case it should be matching the movie rule if it has a lower array index number than the other ones.

Comment: Ok, but why do I get a 404 error ?

Comment: You'll have to share your code for us to figure that out.

Comment: which part of my code should I send ?

Comment: Share the part that creates the custom post type. If you are pluging into the action generate_rewrite_rules to create your own rewrite rules we need to see that too. Finally if you are using add_permastruct show us that code too. Basically everything to do with URL rewriting.

Comment: Also use the download option in rewrite rules inspector to grab your rewrite rules. Upload them to pastebin.com or some such site and post the link here.

Comment: Here are the defined rewrite rules : http://pastebin.com/xkJ9emAd

Comment: @Stephan please edit additional details into your answer so it is more visible.

Comment: You have some rewrite rules missing. But they shouldn't be causing 404 errors for URLs that include the post slug (like the one in your question). So maybe the problem is with your code. How about posting that?